# 1790 brick Federal home with fieldstone foundation

Tags: walls, stone

We live in a 1790 brick federal upstate NY with a fieldstone foundation.  The basement has above ground windows, and is the same footprint as the upstairs floors.  The walls of the basement are all stone.  Basement has 7 foot ceilings.

I would love to fix the stone, and perhaps insulate the inside exterior walls in some way.

Lime mortaring perhaps?

But what would I have to do to create actual interior plasterboard walls for the basement?

Comment: a bit more info. do you just want an interior wall, no historical fidelity, or do you want to have period style plastering?

Comment: I would like to insulate the outside walls - so we can use the basement as a work space.  So I don’t know what the options are taking that into account